# Closing a SWT application after certain time of inactivity

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to close a SWT application after certain period of inactive time. I'm finding difficulty in calculating the inactivity period.All that I've tried just shuts the application after the specified amount of time, irrespective of whether I'm still working on the Application.

Below is the code of what I've tried

```
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    display.asyncExec(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            while(!shell.isDisposed()){
                if (!display.readAndDispatch()){ //if the system is idle

                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() { //schedule timer which will trigger after 1min.

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            logout();
                        }
                    }, 60000);

                }
                else{    // reschedule the timer
                    timer.cancel();
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

with this I'm just able to logout after 1 min even if the user is performing something. Is there a way we can check the inactivity time in SWT ?

Comment: Maybe use `Display.addFilter` to listen to the various events that you consider are 'activity' and maintain a last active time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Display.addFilter` to listen for various events that make the app 'active'. Use `Display.timerExec` to run code in the UI thread repeatedly to check the time since the last event.

Maybe something like:

```
private Instant lastActive;

....

   lastActive = Instant.now();

   final Listener listener = new Listener()
    {
      @Override
      public void handleEvent(final Event event)
      {
        lastActive = Instant.now();
      }
    };

   display.addFilter(SWT.MouseMove, listener);
   display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, listener);
   // TODO more filters if required

   final Runnable timer = new Runnable()
    {
      @Override
      public void run()
      {
        final Instant now = Instant.now();

        if (ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(lastActive, now) > xxx) {  // Number of inactive seconds here
          System.out.println("inactive");  // Inactive code here
        }
        else {
          display.timerExec(1000, this);
        }
      }
    };

   display.timerExec(1000, timer);

   ... create/open shell ...

   while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }
```

Comment: Sir, you are awesome.